# Selecting tab content with the same element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I really need your help,

Since my tabs are generated dynamically, they have the same look and feel as the others with the using the same element id. For example, how can I individually go into the tab content whose element name is: XAL-2018-789101 and set the value of the input id "fileno". Or should I restructuring this using another method? because its not your average form with just one form element using a unique id each and every time to individualize the form elements?

An answer using jQuery is also fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="tabs_container" style="display: none;">

            <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a href='#tab1'>XAL-2018-123456</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tab2'>XAL-2018-789101</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tab3'>XAL-2018-111213</a></li>
            </ul>   

            <div class="tab_container">

                <div class="tab_wrapper">

                    <div id='tab1' class='tab_content' name='XAL-2018-123456'><input type="text" id="fileno"></div>
                    <div id='tab2' class='tab_content' name='XAL-2018-789101'><input type="text" id="fileno"></div>
                    <div id='tab3' class='tab_content' name='XAL-2018-111213'><input type="text" id="fileno"></div>

                </div>

            </div>      

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the dynamically created elements all have the same ID? Because that's a big sign your going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Yes, how else should tab content with the same fields be identified? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Do you control how the tabs are dynamically generated? If not, do you know the name values like `XAL-2018-789101` before hand? Can you use those to find the input you want?

Comment: new tabs are added the minute the user fills in a file number, clicks add new tab and then with a whole other bunch of form field elements are added

Comment: how are you templating those new tabs?

Comment: So @BobbyJones, take a look at my answer again. I've added yet a third code snippet that may be more like what you're looking for. The tab is being created dynamically, and the file-no input's value is being updated on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will handle the "going to the relevant tab" bit -- but what is it you're trying to use to populate that input?

```js
// Hide all tabs but the first
$(".tab_content").hide().first().show();
$(".tabs li a").on("click", function(event) {
  // keep the anchor from triggering.
  event.preventDefault();
  // get the clicked anchor
  let tabEl = $(this);
  // get its text
  let targetName = tabEl.text();
  // use that text to choose the right tab.
  $(".tab_wrapper [name='" + targetName + "']").show().siblings().hide();
})
```

```css
.tab-container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #555;
}

#tab1 {
  background: red;
}

#tab2 {
  background: grey;
}

#tab3 {
  background: lavender;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs_pane">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href='#tab1'>XAL-2018-123456</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>XAL-2018-789101</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>XAL-2018-111213</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab_container">

    <div class="tab_wrapper">

      <div id='tab1' class='tab_content' name='XAL-2018-123456'>
        <input type="text" id="fileno">
      </div>
      <div id='tab2' class='tab_content' name='XAL-2018-789101'>
        <input type="text" id="fileno">
      </div>
      <div id='tab3' class='tab_content' name='XAL-2018-111213'>
        <input type="text" id="fileno">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

if, instead, you simply want to put the content of the link selected into the text input, try something like this. It's very similar to the above, but there's only one tab el, and I'm actually sticking something into the text field.

```js
// No tabs to hide in this case -- we're just
//  toggling the content of a single 'tab'.
$(".tabs li a").on("click", function(event){
  // stop the anchor from doing what anchors do
  event.preventDefault();
  // save a reference to the clicked link.
  let tabEl = $(this);
  // save the text of the clicked link.
  let targetName = tabEl.text();
  // get a reference to the tab pane.
  let tabPane = $(".tab_content");
  
  // set the value of the input to the text.
  tabPane.children("#fileno").val(targetName);
  
})
```

```css
.tab-container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #555;
}
#tab1 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs_pane">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href='#tab1'>XAL-2018-123456</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>XAL-2018-789101</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>XAL-2018-111213</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab_container">

    <div class="tab_wrapper">

      <div class='tab_content'>
        <input type="text" id="fileno">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

So the question has changed. The tab is dynamic, the content is being updated, the input is a text input that is used to populate the file-no field in the form on the new tab. Is that a valid recap? If so, this may do what you're looking for. Largely, this is ripped straight from the jQueryUI page about dynamic tabs.

```js
// use jqueryUI to create my tabs.
let tabs = $("#tabs_pane").tabs();

// handle the click on the 'add tab' button
$(".add-tab").on("click", addTab);

// save a reference to the input field for the new tab
let tabNameEl = $("[name='file-no']"),
  // create the text for any new tabs -- not the tab pane, but the tab.
  tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a></li>",
  // get the count for the NEXT tab to be created.
  tabCounter = $(".tab-pane").length + 1;

// Actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
function addTab() {
  // If there is a value to the fileno field, otherwise default.
  var label = tabNameEl.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
    // set an id on this tab
    id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
    // create the LI for the tabs list
    li = $(tabTemplate.replace(/#\{href\}/g, "#" + id).replace(/#\{label\}/g, label)),
    // create the content for the new tab pane. I'm cloning the first tab,
    //  but you may want something a LOT more robust.
    tabContentHtml = $(".tab-pane").first().children().first().clone(),
    // container for the new tab content. Note that i set the ID here.
    newTabEl = $("<div>").attr("id", id).addClass("tab-pane");

  // stick that tab content into the new tab pane, after I have
  //  updated that file-no input field
  tabContentHtml.find("[name='file-no']").val(label);
  newTabEl.append(tabContentHtml)
    // append the tab to the tabs-list.
  tabs.find(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
  // append the tab pane to the actual container
  tabs.append(newTabEl);
  tabs.tabs("refresh");
  
  // I also want to toggle the new pane to be 
  //  the active one...
  tabs.tabs("option", "active", tabCounter-1);
  tabCounter++;
}
```

```css
.tab-container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #555;
}

#tab1 {
  background: red;
}

.add-new-tab {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #333;
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="add-new-tab">
  <label>Add new tab (enter a file no):
    <input type=text name="file-no" />
    <button class="add-tab">
      Add tab
    </button>
  </label>
</div>
<div id="tabs_pane">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href='#tabs-1'>XAL-2018-123456</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tabs-2'>XAL-2018-789101</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tabs-3'>XAL-2018-111213</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-1">
    <form>
      <label>File no:
        <input type="text" name="file-no" value="XAL-2018-123456" />
      </label>
      <fieldset>
        <label>Owner name:
          <input type="text" name="owner-name" />
        </label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-2">
    <form>
      <label>File no:
        <input type="text" name="file-no" value="XAL-2018-789101" />
      </label>
      <fieldset>
        <label>Owner name:
          <input type="text" name="owner-name" />
        </label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-3">
    <form>
      <label>File no:
        <input type="text" name="file-no" value="XAL-2018-111213" />
      </label>
      <fieldset>
        <label>Owner name:
          <input type="text" name="owner-name" />
        </label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```